# Play developer console “An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later.” in 2017 occurs when try to open any section of the console

Tags: android, developer-console

I searched Stack Overflow and web and saw some occurrences of the problem due to missing payment section info or when adding translations or try to display ratings but my problem is it does not work at all after the design is entirely changed in April 2017.

It started on April 28, I wasn't able to open  "app details" when I click an app on the list or "order management" sections but the rest was working fine. I contacted Google Support and informed them about the problem. They told me to clear cache and cookies or try with another browser or incognito mode. I tried incognito and Edge and it worked for 2 or 3 hours, after that time I started to receive same error using chrome incognito or Edge too.

I cleared cache and cookies, un-installed and installed Chrome twice and deleted history for all from history.google.com but it didn't work.

Also one of my friend had contacted me, and he said, he was getting error from play console. I told him: I get the same issue.

Starting from yesterday, I was not be able to even open the main section, can't see the list of the apps, I see blank page with red bar on top, you can see on the image. I, again, contacted support, but I had no answer or suggestions this time. They said they will look into the issue.

I asked them to provide developers **error codes** when an error occurs. Even if you don't have an answer to this problem ask them to provide error codes for us, developers, not to sit in dark. They should also provide FAQ with error codes to help us. I wasted all weekend and May 1 trying to solve this and I don't want to delete anything again if it has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be an issue that would be best handled by a third party's tech support department.

Comment: This started happening to me, but I noticed that there is never the same error message number twice, even though I'm taking the same steps (starting in new incognito tab, logging in, and going directly to the Crashes.

Comment: is there any payment due from the same account which you are using to publish the app?

Answer (score 5):

If you are facing this issue in **july 2020** then the answer is that google has updated the play console and redirected on this url "**https://play.google.com/console**" If you have not redirected automatically to the above link then manually open this link.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me when I was logged into Gmail as several different accounts simultaneously, I think it didn't know who I was anymore. Signed out of all accounts, signed back in as the only one I needed for the console, everything good now.